# A loop for linking files inside directory

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory, ln

I am trying to make a bash script that creates a directory for  a corresponding directory and links some files in it. So I have a list of directories inside of `~/` with files in them called `Lev1_AA, Lev1_AB, Lev1_AC` and so on

In `~/` my script creates a directory called `test` where I want to create a number of directories that are named after the corresponding directories  `Lev1_AA, Lev1_AB, Lev1_AC, ... ,Lev1_AR` in `~/` and link some files inside of these directories.

What I don't know how to do is make a loop so that the script knows what directory belongs to which corresponding directory so that I link the right files.

Comment: The script knows what directory belongs to which corresponding directory by the `path` (relative or absolute). For instance if in your script you do `for i in ~/Lev1_*; do mkdir -p ~/test/"$i"; done` then you have a corresponding `~/Lev1_X` for every `~/test/Lev1_X` directory. You can associate them by the last component of the `path`. Is that what you mean? (the question is unclear on that point)

Comment: Use a combination of "tar cf mydirs.at `find sourcedir -type d`" then "tar -xf mydirs.tar" to create the directories. For "linking" the files, use "find -type f sourcedir | while read F" loop to process each file name , calculate the target name, then execute "ln -s ...".